# Express depricated

Tags: node.js, authentication, basic-authentication, express-session

Can anyone please guide me how to resolve this problem?

Problem:

```
GMT express deprecated res.json(status, obj): Use res.status(status).json(obj) instead at routes\usersRouter.js
RangeError: Invalid status code: [object Object]
```

Code is here:

```
res.json({
     status: 'Registration Successful!',
     user: user
 }, (err) => next(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
`npm update`

and then update the deprecated code as per the change logs from the updated packages.

And the error clearly says that the

```
  res.json({ status: 'Registration Successful!', user: user })
```

is deprecated.

you have to use

```
 res.status('Registration Successful!').json(user})
```

Also, res.json does not have the callback.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome @SufianUddin, If this answer helps you, please approve the same. So that question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

`res.json` does not have callback function, you need to use something like

```
res.json({ status: 'Registration Successful!', user: user });
```